# Google Sheets TIMEVALUE can't parse time string

Tags: google-sheets

```
=TIMEVALUE("14:15:30")
```

returns a #VALUE! error "TIMEVALUE parameter '14:15:30' cannot be parsed to date/time". I searched the web for a bit, and according to some people the time string may use wrong delimiters. But I get the same error if I change all `:` to `.`. Not even Google's support page explain this behavior, and all their examples throw the same error. My spreadsheet locale is Finland, but changing it to United States didn't help.

Edit: Apparently with Finnish locale the formula expects time string to be prefixed with `klo`. Adding that and using `.` as delimiters got the formula working.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]! Thanks for solving your own problem; please [add it as an answer](/help/self-answer) instead of editing it into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently with Finnish locale the formula expects time string to be prefixed with `klo`. Adding that and using `.` as delimiters got the formula working.